# What's common encoders and decodes on Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, encoder

**I do not know whether it's suitable to ask this question here. If not, please tell me , thanks in advance.**

Recently I am working on FFmpeg for Android. Everything works well but its size is too large so I decide to reduce the size.

I think I should at first only enable some encoders that I maybe use. **What's common encoders and decodes on Android?**

In additional, I can use `./configure --list-encoders` to show all available encodes.

Comment: What are you using `ffmpeg` to do? Do you just need to decode or are you encoding as well? What formats do you intend to work with?

Comment: The good practice on mobile is to use hardware codecs. They are not only faster than SW, they also reduce battery consumption significantly. Typically, for video this includes some limited h264. The highest supported profile depends on the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex says in the comments, the support will be different from device to device, but Android does specify minimum sets for given releases:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats